# Rails 3 back tick system call to curl -d hangs server showing 0% transfer progress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, curl

I am trying to schedule a job in [codem](http://www.transcodem.com/). This example shows the correct way to schedule a job:

```
  # === Example
  #   $ curl -d 'input=/tmp/foo.flv&output=/tmp/bar.mp4&preset=h264' http://localhost:3000/api/jobs
```

I need to do this in the `create` of my controller. This works fine if I do this:

```
scheduleCommand = "curl -d 'input=#{rawFilePath}&output=#{completeFilePath}&preset=h264' http://#{request.host_with_port}/api/jobs"
system "#{scheduleCommand} &"
```

This is dandy until I need to use the response that I get from my curl command. `system` only returns `true` if the command runs and `false` if it doesn't. I need the actual response from `curl`. So now I am trying this:

```
scheduleResults = `#{scheduleCommand}`
```

This causes the server to never respond. I went to check out the server to see what it says and it always looks like this:

```
Completed 200 OK in 30.8ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   222    0     0  100   222      0      2  0:01:51  0:01:34  0:00:17     0
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong. If I just output `scheduleCommand` it gives me `curl -d 'input=/home/dgriffith/codem-schedule/public/uploads/seminars/03-14-2014_dh2-mj_boston-ma_seminar-i-raw.MP4&output=/home/dgriffith/codem-schedule/public/uploads/seminars/03-14-2014_dh2-mj_boston-ma_seminar-i.mp4&preset=h264' http://172.16.155.165:3000/api/jobs`. When I copy this directly into the terminal it works fine immediately giving me the curl response as a string. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Running the curl command in the following manner solved the issue for me.

scheduledCommand=`curl -X ...`

Quoting the command within "`" (back-ticks) actually fetches the result and loads it into the variable, rather than the status of execution.

system "#{scheduleCommand} &" would return the status of execution, as in the issue you faced. Back-ticks are the key.

Hope this helps